# Which kind of covers preserve the smooth structure?

Tags: general-topology, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have a topological space $X$ and a cover $S_i$ of $X$. We say $X$ is *coherent* with respect to the cover $S_i$ if $X$ has the weak topology with respect to $S_i$, that is, if $S \subset X$ is open iff $S \cap S_i$ is open for each $i$.

A nice fact is that if $X$ is coherent with respect to $S_i$ then $f:X \to Y$ is continuous iff its restriction to each $S_i$ is continuous, or in other words, in $\mathsf{Top}$,

$$f:X \to Y \text{is a morphism iff its restriction to each $S_i$ is a morphism.}
\tag{1}$$
The main facts I keep in mind are that

- An open cover is coherent (or more generally if the interiors of $S_i$ form a cover, then $S_i$ is coherent)
- A locally finite closed cover is coherent (or more generally, if the closures of a cover $S_i$ are locally finite, then $S_i$ is coherent).

My question is

> What types of covers have property (1) in the category of smooth manifolds?

What kind of covers can we expect to have property (1)? Certainly open covers still work.

I believe this condition is tied up in the notion of a sheaf?

Comment: What kind of cover even makes sense in the category of smooth manifolds other than open covers? Are you going to try to foliate your manifold or something?

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't know, but your asking that question is educational, and gives me things to investigate.

Comment: I suspect you can do this by covering it with, say, *every* smooth immersed/embedded curve in the manifold. But that you can't do it with any practical subset of that. If you could, my calculus students would be happy to hear it...

Comment: What is the source of this definition of 'coherent'?

Comment: @babai One place I've seen it used is in Lee's *Introduction to Topological Manifolds*